# how can remove and update my option with chosen jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to display the data selection based on the retrieval of the foreach using chosen jquery, I have added remove () and chosen () and the chosen format does not work, how do I remove and update the chosen, is my syntax wrong? please help ... sorry if something unclear can be asked to me ..

This is my syntax for chosen

```
$('#acctAccessed').change(function(){

        $('#acctAccessed').find('option').remove();

        var opt = '';

        <?php foreach ($data_from_ctr['account'] as $data) :?>
        $('#acctAccessed').append('<option value="'<?php echo $data['idMst'] ?>'">'<?php echo $data['giroOB']; ?>'</option>');    
            <?php //endforeach ?>;

             $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
```

This is a table format that I want to make chosen

```
 <tr class="odd">
                <td width="150"><strong>Account Access</strong></td>
                <td width="10">:</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <select id="acctAccessed" name="acctAccessed[]" multiple="multiple" class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" data-placeholder="Select account">
                    </select>
                    <input id="chkall" type="checkbox" >Select All</input>
                </td>
```

Comment: Try  `$(".chosen-select").change();`

Comment: what your objective by $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated"); line ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#acctAccessed').change(function(){

                $('#acctAccessed').empty()

                var opt = '';

                <?php foreach ($data_from_ctr['account'] as $data) :?>
                $('#acctAccessed').append('<option value="'<?php echo $data['idMst'] ?>'">'<?php echo $data['giroOB']; ?>'</option>');    
                    <?php //endforeach ?>;

                    //$(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("#acctAccessed").val($("#acctAccessed option:first").val());
            });
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I have rearrange your code and do some changes.

```
$('#acctAccessed').change(function(){       
    var opt = '';
    <?php foreach ($data_from_ctr['account'] as $data) :?>
    opt += '<option value="'<?php echo $data['idMst'] ?>'">'<?php echo $data['giroOB']; ?>'</option>';    
    <?php endforeach; ?>;
    $('#acctAccessed').html(opt);
    $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```